# JS-Calendario with multiday events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the javascript calendario in my project:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/

Now I want to make it possible to view multiday events in my calendar.
Currently the styling only allows a creation of single day events.

Did someone work with calendario and knows how to style and submit multiday events?

Answer (score 0):

Check Github. There you can find [the latest version of Calendario](https://github.com/codrops/Calendario). Than you can add multiple events like this:

```
var events = {
    '09-08-2015' : '<span>Event 1</span><span>Event 2</span>'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can visit this repo which has taken responsibility to maintain Calendario, https://github.com/deviprsd21/Calendario and add multiple events like this

```
var events = {
    '09-08-2015' : [
        {content:'Event 1', url:'optional', note:'optional'},
        {content:'Event 2', catergory:'optional', and more..}
    ]
};
```